# Read-informed statistical phasing

Tags: exome, genetics, phasing

I'm wondering if there are any tools out there that perform statistical phasing of genetic data (e.g. Eagle) that take read-based phasing from GATK into account.  I've found [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/35/14/i242/5529122) which sounds like what I am looking for, but that tool was developed specifically for Hi-C data, and I only have exomes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[shapeit4](https://odelaneau.github.io/shapeit4/) is currently (probably) the most accurate and quickest phasing algorithm which can account for sequencing reads in the model. They suggest you extract the phase information from the reads using [WhatsHap](https://whatshap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) first however. The guide for WhatsHap can be found [here](https://whatshap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html) and has some info on using data processed using GATK.